# HTML input-element too large in div-container (owl-carousel and bootstrap star-rating)

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I think it is a a basic problem. I would like to layout my elements in my html file. I integrate a star rating into my site but it becomes very large inside a "owl-carousel-slider-item" (http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/). If I place the starrating outside the owl item it is scaled correctly (as seen below). I tried all kinds of resizing parameters but I simply do not get it!

```
    <div id="slider" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">  


   <label for="input-2" class="control-label">Style</label>
   <input id="input-2" class="rating rating-loading" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.5" data-size="xs" data-show-caption="false">


   </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.rating-loading {
    width: 15px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: transparent url('../img/loading.gif') top left no-repeat;
    border: none;
}
/*
 * Stars
 */
.rating-container .rating {

    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.rating-disabled .rating {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.rating-container .star {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 3px;
    text-align: center;

}

.rating-container .empty-stars {
    color: #ffffff;

}

.rating-container .filled-stars {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    color: #fde16d;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #777;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #999;

}

.rating-rtl {
    float: right;
}

.rating-animate .filled-stars {
    transition: width 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.25s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.25s ease;
}

.rating-rtl .filled-stars {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.rating-rtl.is-star .filled-stars {
    right: 0.06em;
}

.rating-rtl.is-heart .empty-stars {
    margin-right: 0.07em;

}
```

The output looks like that:

[image]

Comment: Please include your CSS in your question

Comment: Try making `.rating-container` `display: table` and `.rating-container .star` `display:table-cell`

Comment: no, doesn´t work. But thanks for your answer.